# Move semantics and perfect forwarding difference

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

I already got what move semantics is from this question:
[What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)

But I still do not get what perfect forwarding is in relation to move semantics.

Can someone explain in simple english and with a simple example what perfect forwarding means?

Comment: They are orthogonal concepts. Better ask "what is perfect forwarding" than ask for differences between them.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward

Comment: @juanchopanza Orthogonal concepts indeed, unfortunately sharing a common syntax `T&&` :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Plain English-only attempt

The problem is probably too complex to be accurately described by plain English sentences, but one could think of perfect forwarding as a way to move temporary values passed to a function to another one *as if the first function didn't exist at all*, so without any unnecessary copies or assignments. C++11 allows you to do this by introducing some conversion rules between r-value (&&) and l-value (&) references to a type when you try to get a reference (either r-value or l-value) out of them.

**R-value references are a feature of C++11 and they were designed to both address move semantics and perfect forwarding issues**

This is the plain-English explanation but if you want to thoroughly understand the problem, I'd suggest reading the following:

## The problem:

We want some temporary values passed to a function `F` to be passed to another one `E` **without any copy or assignment**.

## Attempts to solve this issue

- If you try to pass it by reference like

  ```
  template<typename T> void F(T& a) { E(a); }
  ```

  you will not be able to use temporaries (they're not l-values)

  ```
  F(1, 2, 3); // Won't work
  ```
- Declaring a reference as `const` prolongs the lifetime of a temporary on the stack (this was historically done to avoid a common dangling reference error) so the following works

  ```
  template<typename T> void E(const T& a) {}

  template<typename T> void F(const T& a) {
      E(a);
  }
  ```

  but the downside is that you'll have to modify the signature of the function(s) to conform to this solution
- If we're interested in the signature of E (it should conform to something) but not in F's one, we might get away with

  ```
  template<typename T> void E(T& a) {}

  template<typename T> void F(const T& a) {
      E(const_cast<T&>(a));
  }
  ```

  but in case this gets called with a **real const** and gets un-constant'ed, that would trigger **undefined behavior**
- An unmaintainable solution could be to define all the variants you need

  ```
  template<typename T> void E(T& a) {}

  template<typename T> void F(T& a) { E(a); }
  template<typename T> void F(const T& a) { E(const_cast<T&>(a)); }
  ```

  but as the number of parameters grow, the number of combinations grows as well: **this is likely to become unmaintainable**

## The solution in C++11

C++11 defines some rules that state

> "[given] a type TR that is a reference to a type T, an attempt to
>   create the type “lvalue reference to cv TR” creates the type “lvalue
>   reference to T”, while an attempt to create the type “rvalue reference
>   to cv TR” creates the type TR."

in human-form (TR = a reference to type T, R = reference):

```
TR      R
T& & -> T&    // an lvalue reference to cv TR (becomes)-> lvalue reference to T 
T& && -> T&   // an rvalue reference to cv TR (becomes)-> TR (lvalue reference to T) 
T&& & -> T&   // an lvalue reference to cv TR (becomes)-> lvalue reference to T 
T&& && -> T&& // an rvalue reference to cv TR (becomes)-> TR (rvalue reference to T)
```

The important takeaway here is that **now you can keep track of the type the function received**: you can receive an l-value and pass the same l-value to E or you can receive an r-value and pass the same r-value (after converting it since an l-value reference to whatever type reference becomes an l-value reference) to E:

```
template<typename T> void E(T&& a) {}

template<typename T> void F(T&& a) { E(static_cast<T&&>(a)); }
```

A synctactic sugar for

```
static_cast<T&&>(a)
```

is

```
std::forward<T>(a); // is the same as static_cast<T&&>(a);
```

so the final code that solves the problem and makes your life easier is

```
template<typename T> void E(T&& a) {}

template<typename T> void F(T&& a) { E(std::forward<T>(a)); }
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/Q9yQ7I)

---

References: Herb Sutter's blog and some other sources which unfortunately I can't find anymore. If anyone has a clue about those please write them in the comments below and I'll update the post. Thanks.

Comment: If all that perfect forwarding is basically just a cast, why do we have to write that cast at all? Wouldn't `template<typename T> void F(T&& a) { E(a); }` work as well? What additional information do we give the compiler by saying `std::forward<T>(a);`?

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with r-value references and [reference collapsing](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) can be more complex than it initially appears.

**Perfect forwarding**

Perfect forwarding is there to ensure that the argument provided to a function is forwarded (passed) to another function with the same value category (basically r-value vs l-value) as [originally provided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

It is typically used with template functions where reference collapsing may have taken place.

It can also be [used within the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24779910/3747990).

Scott Meyers gives the following pseudo code in his [Going Native 2013 presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler) to explain the workings of `std::forward` (at approximately the 20 minute mark);

```
template <typename T>
T&& forward(T&& param) { // T&& here is formulated to disallow type deduction
  if (is_lvalue_reference<T>::value) {
    return param; // return type T&& collapses to T& in this case
  }
  else {
    return move(param);
  }
}
```

**Example**

An example from the site above, an archetypical example is that of `make_unique`

```
template<class T, class... U>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(U&&... u)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<U>(u)...));
}
```

In the example, the arguments for the `unique_ptr` are provided to it through the `make_unique` as if they had been provided directly to `unique_ptr`, i.e. the reference, l-value and r-value nature of the arguments are maintained.

A more concrete example;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

struct A {
  // implementation excluded
};

struct B {
  B(A &) // ctor 1
  {
    std::cout << "ctor 1" << std::endl;
  }
  B(A&&) // ctor 2
  {
    std::cout << "ctor 2" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  auto b1 = std::make_unique<B>(a); // ctor 1 is used
  auto b2 = std::make_unique<B>(A()); // ctor 2 is used
}
```

**In Brief**

Perfect forwarding depends on a handful of fundamental language constructs new to C++11 that form the bases for much of what we now see in generic programming:

- Reference collapsing
- Rvalue references
- Move semantics

The use of `std::forward` is currently intended in the formulaic `std::forward<T>`, understanding how `std::forward` works helps understand why this is such, and also aids in identifying non-idiomatic or incorrect use of rvalues, reference collapsing and ilk.

Thomas Becker provides a nice, but dense [write up](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) on the perfect forwarding problem and solution.