# Allocate memory for a new object from template argument type

Tags: c++, class, templates, memory, new-operator

I want to be able to create a new object of type T as illustrated in this code snippet.

```
template<typename T, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
void ManageDevice(T& device, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2)
{
    auto newDevice = new T{ arg1, arg2 };
    // ... Perform more operations on newDevice
}
```

I am currently using the function like this:

```
CertainClass* device;
ManageDevice(device, arg1, arg2);
```

The compiler returns the error: Cannot convert from "initializer list" to "class of T*".

I also tried:

```
auto newDevice = new decltype(device){ arg1, arg2 };
```

And got the following error:

Error   C2464   'class of T*&': cannot use 'new' to allocate a reference

So I removed the reference with this:

```
using DeviceType = std::remove_reference<decltype(device)>::type;
auto newDevice = new DeviceType{ arg1, arg2 };
```

And I got the first error message again.

*Questions:*

1. **Any idea if this is even legal and what could I do to make it work?**
2. **In an ideal world I would love to call the function by passing directly a pointer to the class instead of an instance of this class, is it possible?**
3. **What would be the name of this?**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This looks like a case where you would want to use perfect forwarding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732926/move-semantics-and-perfect-forwarding-difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your factual and template parameters do not match. When the template is written as

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T& t);
```

and called with

```
D* d;
foo(d);
```

The type of `T` inside template is going to be `D*`. Now, if you try

```
x = new D*{'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

You will get an obvious compilation error, as there is no (pseudo) constructor for pointer which takes those arguments.

To achieve your goals, you should use

```
template<typename T, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
void ManageDevice(T*& device, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2)...
```

In this case, when called with

```
Device* device;
ManageDevice(device...);
```

The actual `T` inside template would be deduced as `Device`.

This was written in assumption that you use `device` as an output parameter. If I guessed, correctly, a better option is to actually return the value, rather than use output parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
T* ManageDevice(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) {
   ...
   return new_device;
}
```

Then, you can call it as

```
auto* device = ManageDevice<Device>(a, b);
```

And while on it, replace T* with `unique_ptr<T>` and `new` with `std::make_unique`.

Comment: I thought of returning the value of the new initialized device, but I want to call this function to create devices of many different classes. With this method I don't understand how the template will call the good constructor of every different T. (I just started using templates)

Comment: @JuBonn good catch, I didn't specify that. Let me put it into the answer as well.

Comment: I can't use smart pointers because of old code dependencies...
But the syntax (T*&) you proposed seems to work for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `ManageDevice(*device, arg1, arg2);` so `T` is deduced to be `CertainClass` so constructor invocation `new T{` will be well-formed. Or, if you are passing a pointer (which probably not a good idea), use `std::remove_pointer` to get object type from `T`:

```
using DeviceType = typename ::std::remove_pointer<T>::type;
```